# compare 2 columns in excel and find out difference

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns in excel. One is main columns and other which i need to compare with main column.

[image]

So what I want is to compare col with main columns if it doesn't matched it colors with yellow or any other color.
End point is I want data not matching with main col should get highlighted.

Tried:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B, $A2)=0, "No match in B", "")
```

this isnt working

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far, and what error are you experiencing?

Comment: researched a lot i got this formula =IF(COUNTIF($B:$B, $A2)=0, "No match in B", "") this isnt working:(

Comment: [Edit] your question to show the code / formulae you have tried, and the error received

Answer (score 1):

The right tool for that is conditional formatting.

supposing your example starts at A0, you would select the cells from A1 to B100 (100 being  the last row of your table), activate the conditional formatting, and had a new rule which would be`$A1<>$B1` and then choose the appropriate formatting.